# $G/H$ is a Factor Group. Are its subgroups isomorphic to other factor groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$, let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Suppose $A$ is a subgroup of $G/H$. Does there exist a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G/K$ is isomorphic to $A$?

Comment: What's your point, @TobiasKildetoft ? I can't see anything strange there...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ahh, I read it as requiring $H\leq K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Several posters have already given the correct formulation of the type of statement you are after. I will give you a counterexample to your statement as is.

Recall that $A_5$, the alternating group on $5$ symbols, is simple (a similar argument will work with any other simple group). $A_5$ is a quotient of $A_5\times A_5$ (just mod out by the first factor). Now we can take a non-trivial subgroup of $A_5$ such as $A_4$. There is no way to realize $A_4$ as a quotient of $A_5\times A_5$.

To see this, suppose we have a homomorphism from $A_5\times A_5$ to $A_4$. Then we have the composition $A_5\to A_5\times A_5 \to A_4$, where the first homomorphism is given by $x\mapsto (x,id)$. Then, since $A_5$ is simple and $A_5$ is larger than $A_4$, our homomorphism $A_5\to A_4$ sends everything to the identity. Thus anything of the form $(x,id)\in A_5\times A_5$ maps to $0$. But we can say the same thing (for the same reasons) about elements of the form $(id,y)$. Since every element $(x,y)$ in $A_5$ can be expressed as a product $(x,id)\cdot (id,y)$, every homomorphism from $A_5\times A_5$ to $A_4$ is thus trivial, and thus there is clearly no surjective homomorphism, as you require.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Correspondence Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29), we can write $\;A=K/H\;$ , with $\;H\le K\le G\;$, but then in fact by the third (or whatever) isomorphism theorem:

$$G/K\cong (G/H)/(K/H)$$

So $\;A\cong G/K\;$ if there's a quotient group of the quotient $\;G/H\;$ isomorphic to $\;A\;$ , and this may happen...and may not happen. For example, it always happens for finite *abelian* groups, say:

$$G=C_8:=\langle c\rangle\;,\;\;H=\langle c^4\rangle\;,\;G/H\cong C_4\;,\;\;A=\langle c^2\rangle/H\cong H\cong G/H\;\;\ (!)$$

Comment: Why would $A$ be such a quotient? You have taken a subgroup of $G/H$, and you conclude that the quotient by the subgroup of $G$ corresponding to this subgroup is a quotient of $G/H$?

Comment: I messed up (in my mind) with the comment I wrote to you, @TobiasKildetoft ...hehe. Editing now. Thanks.

Comment: Now I am really not sure where you are going. If $A$ is a subgroup of $G/H$ then $A$ is a subgroup of $G/H$?

Comment: Edited again...let's see if this time it makes sense wrt what the OP asked.